# Multiple Field Join via Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to figure out how to introduce multiple field matches into this.  Right now I'm joining based on a matching UserId to the company table.  But what if I wanted to also have an AND in there such as `c.SomeField = somevalue`?

```
var companyUsers = users.Where(u => u.IsEmployee)
                        .Join(companies, 
                              u => u.UserId, c => c.UserId, 
                              (u, c) => u.UserId)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: It's a lot easier to read code if you don't have to scroll sideways to see it all... LINQ queries generally work very nicely if you stack them vertically - see my answer for an example...

Answer (score 4):

If `somevalue` is a constant (i.e. unrelated to the user) then you should just filter `companies` first:

```
var companyUsers = users.Where(u => u.IsEmployee)
                        .Join(companies.Where(c => c.SomeField == someValue),
                              u => u.UserId, c => c.UserId, (u, c) => u.UserId)
                        .ToList();
```

If you need to join two fields of the user to two fields of the company, use an anonymous type as shown by SLaks.

Comment: thanks, I don't find LINQ to be that easy sometimes.  Still trying to get fluent in it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to join on anonymous types:

```
as.Join(bs, a => new { a.X, a.Y }, b => new { b.X, b.Y })
```

Comment: @JohnNguyen: Why not? What happened?